# Unity ML Agents Ray Perception Sensor 2D not showing collisions

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, machine-learning

I am still relatively new to the Unity environment and am currently working with reinforcement learning and ML agents. For this I wanted to add an agent to the 2D platformer.

I have attached two ray perception sensors to my agent. Unfortunately I can't get any hits with these sensors, at least they are not displayed as usual with a sphere in the gizmos.

[image: Scene view with gizmos]

The sensors are casting rays, but like you see in the image, they are not colliding.

The ray perception sensor are childs of the agent, defined in its prefab.
I defined the sensors to collide with 4 tags: Untagged, ground, enemy and coin

I assigned the coin tag to the token, the enemy tag to the enemy and the ground tag to the tilemap forming the ground.
The token has a circle collider, while the enemy has an capsule collider.
On the tilemap there is a tilmap collider.

I would now expect the sensor to collide with the token, enemy and ground and display these hits in spheres, but it does not.
So, what am I doing wrong?

[image: Definition of RayPerceptionSensor2D]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot more investigation i figured out the problem myself:

The tags where correctly configured, but i had an misunderstanding in the Ray Layer Mask.

[Ray Layer Mask](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PdCFz.png)

Previously i had configured it to "Everything"/"Default" which resulted in a collision in the sensor itself and seems not right (Despite the player tag was not in the detagtable tags).

After i created more layers and assigned my targets to these layers, everything starts working as intended.

[Working Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/katTc.png)

Maybe this answer will help someone, having similar issues.