# Ray Perception Sensor 2D gizmos not detecting collision

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, raycasting, ml-agent

If I make a new scene with 3d sphere and cube and make the sphere has Ray perception, the gizmos is not detecting any collision.
[image]

This doesn't happen when I try using 3d perception in 3d scene instead.
I have read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67643885/unity-ml-agents-ray-perception-sensor-2d-not-showing-collisions), and have tried doing the same but it's still not showing any red lines representing a collision.

Currently I have added a new Collectible layer and tag, and assign it to the Cubes, with Untagged tag and Default layer for the Sphere object.

Here's my settings for the Sphere object's Ray Perception
[image: Here's my settings for the Sphere object's Ray Perception]

edit: image above is wrong (as mentioned in the ans), I have tried this but still doesn't work
[image]

And this is my layer and tag for the Cube
[image: And this is my layer and tag for the Cube]

I expect it to show red spheres showing collision like this in 3d scene.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general: As the name suggests the `RayPerceptionSensor2D` works for **2D** colliders

In Unity the 2D and 3D Physics are two completely separate engines that don't interact in any way!

So either use `Collider2D` like `BoxCollider2D`, `CirlceCollider2D` etc or use a `RayPerceptionSensor3D`  and configure and **rotate** it accordingly so that it only rays in XY direction.

---

Besides that you say you have a layer and tag `Collectible` in your description and the second screenshot shows this, but in your sensor you are searching for `Obstacle` ... which basically would funnily make this a duplicate of the question you linked ;)

---

And again in general: Afaik you don't need both, tags and layers. One should be enough, except you really need to go with both systems since you have e.g. multiple different category objects on the same layer you raycast, then you want to filter them using tags.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have tried your suggestion to use 3d perception and rotate it using a child game object and it works! Thanks for that.

And using the box collider 2d also works